# Limit with 3 variables approaching infinite

Tags: limits

I'm having some problems resolving this limit. The fact is that I'm finding little information about limits in three variables online and in my manuals, and even less information about three variables approaching infinite. This is (one) of the limits:

$\lim_{x,y,z\to \infty}\frac{1+xy}{xz^2}$

My idea is to split the fraction in two:

$=\lim_{x,y,z\to \infty}\frac{1}{xz^2}+\lim_{x,y,z\to \infty}\frac{y}{z^2}$

Now the first one obviously goes to zero but I'm not sure about the second part going to zero too.

Comment: Your idea is good but it is not necessary. The strategy to deal with these kind of limits is at first to make the foundamental choice that is: the limit exsts or the limit doesn't exist. In that case it seems not so prone to exists. Then the way to show that is find diefferent limits for different paths. Of course the paths need to be consistent with the fact that $\|(x,y,z)\|\to \infty$. For example we can't assume $y=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

- for $z^2=y \implies \frac{1+xy}{xz^2}=\frac{1+xy}{xy} \to 1$
- for $-z^2=y \implies \frac{1+xy}{xz^2}=\frac{1+xy}{-xy} \to -1$

Comment: So you're trying to reach infiniy using two "curves" and you show that with different "curves" the result is different?

Comment: @JJmate Yes exactly, maybe it is more correct to talk of different paths! That's the standard way to show that a limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Gimusi.You have y=-z^2, but lim x,y,z to (+!!) infty.No problem?

Comment: Is there a way to parametrize my paths in limits involving three variables like i used to do with two variables? As example i usually show the existance of a limit in two variables reaching zero with the lines (t,mt)

Comment: @JJmate Yes of course in that case as $t \to \infty$ we can assume  for example $(x,y,z)=(t,t^2,t)$ for the first path and $(x,y,z)=(t,-t^2,t) $ for the second one.

Comment: I decided to put all the info you gave me together in order to find a solution. I demonstrate that reaching infinite with the path (t,mt^2,t) depends on the value of m (so depends on the path) and this is enough (I think) to demonstrate that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @JJmate Sorry if  agave info in a sparse way. I hope that all is clear now. In case, do not hesitate to ask for more information about that. Bye

Comment: You totally helped me out! I don't really know if the comment of @PeterSzilas is a struggle for your answer but i think that with my solution involving variable _m_ I truly bypass that problem

Comment: @PeterSzilas Sorry Peter I didn't notice your comment! Usually the meaning of $(x,y,z) \to \infty$ is that$ \|(x,y,z)\| \to \infty$ that is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\to \infty$ therefore also the path $y=-z^2$ is suitable to show that the limit doesn't exist. If we want stay positive just assume $y=z^2/2$.

Comment: @JJmate Sorry I didn't see the comment by Peter, I've added something on that.